# Apache2: nested require statements within Location

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, active-directory, ldap

I'd like to set up different LDAP authorization rules for different levels of an URL. This is the config currently used

```
    <Location />
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Foo"
            AuthBasicProvider ldap
            AuthLDAPURL "..."
            AuthLDAPBindDN  "..."
            AuthLDAPBindPassword "..."
    </Location>

    <Location />
            Require ldap-group cn=foo,ou=Groups,dc=com,dc=company
    </Location>

    <Location /path/>
            Require ldap-user bar
    </Location>
```

The problem is that `/path/` *inherits* the rules from `/`. Hence for user `bar` to be able to access `/path/` he must also be in the `foo` group.

How can I configure the user `bar` to be able to access `/path/` without also having to be a member of group `foo`?

---

**EDIT:** Changed `ldap-group` to `ldap-user` for `/path/` for an accurate problem description.

Comment: Mm ... try placing more specific ones first, i.e., `/path/` and the main one `/` last in the list ... ? Unsure if it will work, but worth a try ...

Comment: @km01, I tried that also without success

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and by seeking around, I found the apache directive AuthMerging which handles such situation.

The [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_core.html#authmerging) says that the default is `AuthMerging Off` (last authorization is the only one), but the above described effect seems to imply that the value is `And` (last authorization restricts the previous one). The other possibility is `Or` (last authorization extends the previous one). In my case, this is this `Or` value that I wanted, and it worked when adding the `Auth;Merging Or` directive inside the lower `Location` level.

Maybe the default value is different for `Directory` and `Location` sections, but I didn't find anything about that.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding (and I just struggled to find solid supporting documentation) is that Location directives are cumulative, so you're essentially applying two Require directives.  What if you did something like this:

```
<LocationMatch "/[^path]">
    Require ldap-group cn=foo,ou=Groups,dc=com,dc=company
</Location>

<Location /path/>
    Require ldap-group cn=bar,ou=Groups,dc=com,dc=company
</Location>
```

You'll have to check if that regular expression is apache-compatible, but I believe this approach will work.

Comment: If that is a regular expression, then it will _not_ do what you think!  That expression matches anything that starts with a `/` not followed by any of the letters `p`, `a`, `t`, or `h` - thus it will reject `/path` but it will also reject `/acct` and `/home`.

Comment: Hm, you're right.  A regexp for ! /path would be more complicated, but possible.

Comment: I can't seem to find a straight regexp for "don't match this string." I've tried `sed` and `perl` to no avail. In particular, these fail: `/[^p][^a][^t][^h]` and `/(path){0,0}`. Neither works. Is the only possibility to use a "don't match this regexp"?

Comment: It's ugly, but this works (at least in `ruby -ne`): `/^\/[^p]{1}[^a]{1}[^t]{1}[^h]{1}/`.  Would be nice if there was a LocationNotMatch directive :)...

Comment: What would that regex do with `/pathworks`? Methinks it would treat it just the same as `/path`, yes?

Comment: Shoot, you're right.  Hmm.